# What HTTP address can I send requests to from when hosting on Heroku? (client to server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, heroku

This sounds really dumb, but...

I have a Node.js Express server that used to be completely functioning on my localhost. I recently deployed it on Heroku and made some changes so my actual index.js listens to process.env.PORT instead of localhost. it listens to process.env.PORT fine through that, but I have a page rendered in React.js called app.js stored within a directory (./js/app.js) that makes HTTP requests when buttons are clicked.

However, whenever I try accessing process.env.PORT from within the app.js to make these requests, process is undefined, so everything falls apart. When working on it locally, I would just send the requests to http://localhost:3000/database, but now I have to change that since it's deployed on Heroku now.

How can I communicate between my client (app.js) and my server (index.js)?

I know this is something super simple and I've tried searching for it for the past couple of hours, but I just don't know how to phrase it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you communicating through AJAX ? Can you show code from the app.js file that is trying to communicate to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your address and port in your app.js file as a heroku server address:

```
var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port; // put your adress here :)

console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I am there if you get another pb :)

Comment: My app.js doesn't contain the server info, but rather it's what's rendered for the client. My issue is that I don't know how to get the client to communicate with the server. Thank you for your help! (: